# node js call mysql stored procedure doesnt worked for me blow my code

Tags: mysql, nodes

```
app.get('/pool', function (req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
        else {
            console.log("connection");
            connection.query('sp_LI_UploadData_Get', function (err, results, fields) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }
                res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
            });

        }

    });
});
```

I got this error {"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sp_LI_UploadData_Get' at line 1","sqlState":"42000","index":0,"sql":"sp_LI_UploadData_Get"}

Comment: MySQL requires stored procedures to be called with `CALL sp()` -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you call sp() works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Call sp()** works for solving this issue...

```
connection.config.query('call sp_LI_UploadData_Add(?)',
            [0],
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    //next(err);
                    res.send('Error');
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
                else { }
```